# Grouping of list in a nested list in sequential order

Tags: python

```
    I have the following data structure( a list of lists)    
    
        [
          [['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'M1'],
          [['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'PAD'], 'M1'],
          [['A', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD'], 'M2'],
          [['A', 'A', 'A', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD'], 'M3']
        ]
    
I have a nested_list where i need to perform grouping of lists in sequential order, where i get the input in order and grouping should be done in same sequential input order
```

1.Group list by element in it
2.Grouping should be done sequential order, not randomly
3.Remove 'PAD' element in a list

so the dictionary would look like this

```
       {
          "M1" : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A','B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
          "M2" : ['A'],
          "M3" : ['A', 'A', 'A']
        }
```

Comment: At what part of your code are you stuck?

Comment: I can able to group them in random order, but i need in sequential order as showed in expected output

Comment: Please show the relevant code you are currently using, and indicate where is the problematic part/bug.

Comment: When you say sequential order, do you mean the input order, or ordered e.g. alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
output={}
for i in example_list:
    for j in i[0]:
        i[0]=[p for p in i[0] if p != 'PAD']
    if i[1] in output:
        i[0]=output[i[1]]+i[0]
    output.update({i[1]:i[0]})
output=dict(sorted(output.items()))
from pprint import pprint
pprint(output)
```

Output:

```
{'MI21071001863': ['B-URLA',
                   'I-URLA',
                   'I-URLA',
                   'I-URLA',
                   'L-URLA',
                   'U-Loan Application',
                   'U-URLA',
                   'U-Written List Of Service Providers',
                   'B-URLA',
                   'I-URLA',
                   'L-URLA',
                   'U-Loan Application',
                   'B-URLA',
                   'I-URLA',
                   'L-URLA'],
 'MI21071003044': ['U-Geocode'],
 'MI21071004456': ['B-Loan Closing Advisor Feedback Certificate',
                   'I-Loan Closing Advisor Feedback Certificate',
                   'L-Loan Closing Advisor Feedback Certificate']}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I see that "MI21071001863", it has 2 list but output generating only 1 list, can you please check and update it

Comment: Updated to append with prev elements

Comment: works like gem!

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the following code:

```
testList = [
      [['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'PAD'], 'M1'],
      [['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'M1'],
      [['A', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD'], 'M2'],
      [['A', 'A', 'A', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD', 'PAD'], 'M3']
    ]

newDict = {}

for childList in testList:
    if newDict.get(childList[1]):
        newDict.update({
            childList[1]: newDict[childList[1]] + list((x for x in childList[0] if x !='PAD' ))
        })
    else:
        newDict.update({
            childList[1]: list((x for x in childList[0] if x !='PAD' ))
        })
    
print(newDict)
# output: 
# {'M1': ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
# 'M2': ['A'], 
# 'M3': ['A', 'A', 'A']}
```

Comment: Working as expected, thanks for answering.